# Emmet for PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm, emmet

Обновил PHP Storm до 2019 версии и теперь во время набора текста всплывают такие подсказки, вместо тех что мне нужно. Подскажите, что это за плагин чтобы я мог его отключить? Как я понял, это не Emmet.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что за подсказки не нравятся? Свойства с `mso-` префиксом? Они всегда были в комплишене (для совместимости с ReSharper). это специальные стили для работы с Microsoft Office

Comment: Они мне не нужны. Я хотел бы их удалить

Comment: никак не получится:(

Comment: Не подскажите что это за настройки? Возможно, смогу их отключить.

Comment: нет никаких настроек, иначе я бы уже написала.

Comment: так что получается, возвращаться на старую версию шторма?)

Comment: так и в старой все это было...

Comment: Так в первой же строке `display: none;`; а вообще, я например давно сделал свои Live Templates и не парюсь об Emmet.